# Kernel linux module with threads which use a completion variable to synchronize their work

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have a program with threads which use a completion variable to synchronize their work. And i need help how to do it or what function to use so that the reader thread tells the writer thread that it has finished reading.

```
     #include<linux/module.h>
     #include<linux/kthread.h>
     #include<linux/wait.h>
     #include<linux/completion.h>
     #include<linux/slab.h>
     #include <linux/spinlock.h>




     enum thread_index {WAKING_THREAD, WRITER_THREAD, READER_THREAD};

     static struct thread_structure
     {
     struct task_struct *thread[3];
     } threads;

     static wait_queue_head_t wait_queue;
     static bool condition;
     static DECLARE_COMPLETION(number_completion);
     static int number;




    static int work; 


     static int writer_thread(void *data)
    {
     DEFINE_WAIT(wait);
     for(;;) {

     number++;
     complete(&number_completion);

     add_wait_queue(&wait_queue,&wait);
     while(!condition) {
     prepare_to_wait(&wait_queue,&wait,TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
     if(kthread_should_stop())
            return 0;
     printk(KERN_INFO "[writer_thread]: awake\n");
     schedule();
     }
     condition=false;
     finish_wait(&wait_queue,&wait);
     }
     }

     static int reader_thread(void *data)
     {

     DEFINE_WAIT(wait);
    for(;;) {


     wait_for_completion(&number_completion);



     pr_info("[reader_thread] Number value: %d\n",number);

     if(kthread_should_stop())
     return 0;
     schedule();

     }
     }

     static int waking_thread(void *data)
     {
     for(;;) {



     if(kthread_should_stop())
     return 0;
     set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
     if(schedule_timeout(1*HZ))
     printk(KERN_INFO "Signal received!\n");
     condition=true;
     wake_up(&wait_queue);
     }

     }

     static int __init threads_init(void)
     {
     init_waitqueue_head(&wait_queue);
     threads.thread[READER_THREAD] = kthread_run(reader_thread,NULL,"reader_thread");
     threads.thread[WRITER_THREAD] = kthread_run(writer_thread,NULL,"writer_thread");
     threads.thread[WAKING_THREAD] = kthread_run(waking_thread,NULL,"waking_thread");

     return 0;
     }

     static void __exit threads_exit(void)
     {

     kthread_stop(threads.thread[READER_THREAD]);
     kthread_stop(threads.thread[WAKING_THREAD]);
     kthread_stop(threads.thread[WRITER_THREAD]);

     }

     module_init(threads_init);
     module_exit(threads_exit);

     MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
     MODULE_DESCRIPTION("kernel linux threads and a completion variable.");
     MODULE_AUTHOR("Jeka");
```

the program works correctly, but I need to follow it so that I can see that the reader thread informs the writer theard about the reading assurance

Comment: Please indent your code properly. To put code inside a visual "code block" indent it with 4 spaces. Or highlight the snippet with mouse and press the `{}` button in formatting tab (it will just prepend the text with 4 spaces).

Comment: You are using `complete()` and `wait_for_completion()` in loops, but once a completion object has been marked "complete", it remains complete. To reset a completion object back to the "not complete" state, you need to use the `reinit_completion()` function.

Comment: It seems you work on the same (or very related) project, as the author of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367001/after-using-rmmod-program-freezes). It is not bad by itself, but make sure you don't repeat the errors revealed in the other question. (I mean `return 0;` without executing `finish_wait` in the `writer_thread`). And.. the other question has better formatting of the code than yours one. It is really difficult to read the code without indented blocks of code enclosed into `{..}`.